# rolling back datbabase changes with sqlcmd utility

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, sqlcmd, invoke-sqlcmd

I have a release pipeline which applies database changes with 'SqlCmd.exe'.
I am trying to execute a stored procedure using this command-line utility:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S tcp:$(Server) -d $(Database) -U $(UserName) -P '$(Password)' -b -i "$(ScriptFile)"
```

Once something goes wrong in the script file, I want to  SQLCMD.EXE automatically rollback all the changes.

I should mention that there is no TRANSACTIONS management inside the script file.

Please help me to learn how to resolve this.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer, how did it go on this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to add rollback transactions in your script file. There is not configurations in azure release pipeline to control the rollback behavior. See [example here](https://www.sqlshack.com/rollback-sql-rolling-back-transactions-via-the-rollback-sql-query/) to add transactions in scripts.

If you donot want to add transactions in the script file. You can try adding a poweshell task in release pipeline run below script to append a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `END TRANSACTION` to your query contents.

```
$fullbatch = @()
$fullbatch += "BEGIN TRANSACTION;"

$fullbatch += Get-Content $(ScriptFile)
 
$fullbatch += "COMMIT TRANSACTION;"

sqlcmd -S tcp:$(Server) -d $(Database) -U $(UserName) -P '$(Password)' -b -Q "$fullbatch"
```

See example in [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93599/transaction-with-multiple-sqlcmd-calls-in-a-batch-file).